# Relative path to a file from an HTML template using gulp-file-include

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, gulp

What is the recommended way to link to CSS and JavaScript files from within an HTML template using [**gulp-file-include**](https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include)?

Example:

**index.html**

```
@@include('templates/doc-begin.html')
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Hello!</p>
@@include('templates/doc-end.html')
```

**support/index.html**

```
@@include('templates/doc-begin.html')
<h1>Support</h1>
<p>RTFM</p>
@@include('templates/doc-end.html')
```

**templates/doc-begin.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
   <title>Website</title>
   <link rel=stylesheet href=?????/style.css>
</head>
<body>
```

The two `index.html` files are at different folder levels, so the relative path to the stylesheet in the `link` tag cannot be hardcoded (absolute paths have their own problems and are undesirable in this case).

Basically the first `link` tag needs to be something like:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=style.css>
```

and the second something like:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href=../style.css>
```

Is there a convenient way in **gulp-file-include** to do this?

*Note:*
I currently have a workaround where I pass a variable as `"."`, `".."`, or `"../.."` into each `@@include` call, but that's cumbersome and brittle.

Comment: Feature request:
https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include/issues/115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no answer has been posted, here's my workaround:

**index.html**

```
@@include('templates/doc-begin.html', { "webRoot": "." })
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>Hello!</p>
@@include('templates/doc-end.html', { "webRoot": "." })
```

**support/index.html**

```
@@include('templates/doc-begin.html', { "webRoot": ".." })
<h1>Support</h1>
<p>RTFM</p>
@@include('templates/doc-end.html', { "webRoot": ".." })
```

**templates/doc-begin.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
   <title>Website</title>
   <link rel=stylesheet href=@@webRoot/style.css>
</head>
<body>
```

*Update (April 2017):*
The `webRoot` feature has been added to **gulp-file-include**.
https://github.com/coderhaoxin/gulp-file-include#webroot-built-in-context-variable